# js: accessing scope of parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, scope, parent

I have a jquery class within a normal class in javascript. Is it possible to access variables in the scope of the parent class from a callback function in the jquery class?

A simple example of what I mean is shown below

```
var simpleClass = function () {    
    this.status = "pending";
    this.target = jqueryObject;
    this.updateStatus = function() {
        this.target.fadeOut("fast",function () {
           this.status = "complete"; //this needs to update the parent class 
        });
    };
};
```

Now in the above example,  the callback function tries to access the scope of the jquery object. is there any way to access the status variable in the parent class?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You set "this" to a variable in the parent function and then use it in the inner function.

```
var simpleClass = function () {         
    this.status = "pending";     
    this.target = jqueryObject;     

    var parent = this;

    this.updateStatus = function() {         
            this.jqueryObject.fadeOut("fast",function () {            
                parent.status = "complete"; //this needs to update the parent class          
            });     
        }; 
    };
```

Comment: That wont work parent is in the scope of simpleClass not of the jquery object

What you have to remeber is jQuery call back code is called as its own function noting to do with where it was set

Comment: @Barkermn01 the variable is accessible by the powers of closures! https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: Bull the scopes, jQuery callbacks are not called in the scope of the class that defined them

Comment: i know this with all call back system coz i have to add a var to the XMLHttpRequest to have another objects access inside the XMLHttpRequest i use varName.API = this; then in the callback i get the srcElement from the provided object so it's not in the global scope but still accessible

Comment: @Barkermn01 It's amusing the way you are in denial. What Humberto said is correct. Give it a try.

Answer (score 45):

I will post this answer to this old question anyway as no one yet posted this before.

You can use the `bind` method on your function calls to define the scope which  `this` belongs to.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Normaly everytime you create a method - `this` belongs to the current scope of the function. Variables from scope2 can't see variables from scope1.

e.g.

```
function(){
    // scope 1
    this.baz = 'foo';

    function(){
        // scope 2
        this.baz // not defined
    };
};
```

with the `bind` method you can define the scope from `this` inside the function. So using  `.bind(this)` you're telling the called function that their own scope from `this` is referred to the scope of the parent function, like:

```
function(){
    // scope 1
    this.baz = 'foo';

    function(){
        // scope 1
        this.baz // foo
    }.bind(this);
};
```

so in your case, this would be an example using the `bind` method

```
var simpleClass = function () {    
    this.status = "pending";
    this.target = jqueryObject;
    this.updateStatus = function() {
        this.target.fadeOut("fast",function () {
           this.status = "complete"; //this needs to update the parent class 
        }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this);
};
```

Comment: This perfectly solves the issue when attempting to access a nested `this` object within a JavaScript class. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. Helped me out big time!!

Answer (score 12):

Use an [**Arrow Function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function does not have it's own `this`. The `this` value of the enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal variable lookup rules. So while searching for `this` which is not present in current scope they end up finding `this` from its enclosing scope.

**Normal function syntax**

`function(param1, param2) {}`

**Arrow function syntax**

`(param1, param2) => {}`

**Usage**

```
const simpleClass = function () {    
    this.status = "pending";
    this.target = jqueryObject;
    this.updateStatus = function() { 
        this.target.fadeOut("fast", () => { // notice the syntax here
           this.status = "complete"; // no change required here
        });
    };
};
```

**Using an Arrow function within a ECMAScript 2015 Class**

```
class simpleClass {

    constructor() {
        this.status = 'pending';
        this.target = jqueryObject;
    }

    updateStatus() {
        this.target.faceOut('fast', () => {
            this.status = "complete";
        });
    }
}

const s = new simpleClass();
s.updateStatus();
```

**Described code works only in [modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions).**

Answer (score 4):

By setting **"this"** to a variable you can access easily. Like:

```
$("#ImageFile").change(function (e) {
    var image, file;
    var Parent=this;
    if ((file = Parent.files[0])) {
        var sFileExtension = file.name.split('.')[file.name.split('.').length - 1];

        if (sFileExtension === "jpg" || sFileExtension === "jpeg" || sFileExtension === "bmp" || sFileExtension === "png" || sFileExtension === "gif") {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
               alert(Parent.files[0].name);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(Parent.files[0]);
        }
        else { alert('Wrong file selected. Only jpg, jpeg, bmp, png and gif files are allowed.'); }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry m8. You have to nest the reference down into the objects like so:

```
var simpleClass = function () {
    var _root = this;
    this.status = "pending";
    this.target = jqueryObject;
    this.updateStatus = function() {
        this.root = _root;
        _root.target.fadeOut("fast",function () {
           this.status = "complete"; //this needs to update the parent class 
        });
    };
};
```

notice the `var _root`

Comment: ok i se now that i could have used `this.root.target` instead of `_root.target` but its the same, so it doesn't matter :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
   var sc = (function(scc){

    scc = {};

    scc.target = jQueryObject;


    scc.stt = "stt init";

    scc.updateStatus = function(){
        var elem = this;

        this.target.click(function(){
            elem.stt= "stt change";
            console.log(elem.stt);
        })

    }

    return scc;


}(sc || {}));
```

you can also define your target object as private variable

Comment: Somehow, I like this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can mantain state using closure variables:

```
function simpleClass() {
   var _state = { status: "pending", target: jqueryObject; }

   this.updateStatus = function() {
      this.target.fadeOut("fast",function () {
         _state.status = "complete"; //this needs to update the parent class 
      });
   }
}

// Later...
var classInstance = new simpleClass();
```