# Accessing class property from function nested in object

Tags: javascript, class, typescript, this

*Edit: I've replaced my initial example with something closer to my actual code, which still demonstrates the same issue (both on JSFiddle and on TypeScript's playground.)*

Say I have a Typescript class defined like below, where one property is accessed by a getter nested in another object property. Clearly, `this` inside of the `weekdays.monday` getter is referencing `weekdays`, and not `actual`.

```
class DayOfWeekSelector {
  private actual = {
    monday: false,
    /*tuesday - sunday would go here*/
  }

  public weekdays = {
    get monday() {
      return this.actual.monday;
    },
    set monday(newVal) {
      this.actual.monday = newVal;
    },
    /*tuesday - sunday would go here*/
  }
}

const dow = new DayOfWeekSelector();

//I want this to read the value of the 'monday' property of the private 'actual' object
//but instead, it tries to read 'actual' as a property of 'weekdays', and fails
console.log(dow.weekdays.monday);
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/dimmreaper/4v6k6ssx/

I know that in this simple demonstration, I could just extract the getter out of the object into a property directly on the class, and then `this` would reference the class. But is there another way to access properties of `DayOfWeekSelector` from getters and setters within another object on the class, without adding clutter?

Comment: You better provide a full code, not this simple demonstration, eith the problem you are having.

Comment: If you run the above code in [The Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//) it prints "inaccessible from myFunc".  So, uh, what's the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [js: accessing scope of parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106284/js-accessing-scope-of-parent-class)

Comment: JSFiddle prints "inaccessible" as well if you configure it to run with Babel. If you don't run with Babel... you can't run this code, because class property initializers are not in standard JS yet?

Comment: @eli-bd That scenario is easily solved by setting a reference to `this` outside the function. How would I do that in this scenario?

Comment: I can't easily tell how JSFiddle is transpiling TypeScript, but it looks like the arrow function is changed into a regular function without the required `this`-juggling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use class property syntax but write them explicitly in the constructor, where you can use local variables:

```
class DayOfWeekSelector {
  public weekdays;
  constructor() {
    const actual = {
      monday: false,
      /*tuesday - sunday would go here*/
    };
    this.weekdays = {
      get monday() {
        return actual.monday;
      },
      set monday(newVal) {
        actual.monday = newVal;
      },
      /*tuesday - sunday would go here*/
    };
  }
}
const dow = new DayOfWeekSelector();
console.log(dow.weekdays.monday);
```

Of course, if those are your actual getters and setters that don't do anything but access the "private" object, there is no advantage to using them at all, it's much simpler to directly expose the `actual` object.

Comment: Good idea! I didn't know I could do it this way. And yeah, my full code has logic around each day; they're not just simple getters/setters.